# oci_connect and prompt command

Tags: php, oracle, prompt

I am executing Oracle requests from PHP code and display the results as it comes. Sometimes, I need to use 'prompt' inside the requests, in order to display a title, so I want this text in the result.

The strange thing is that a request like 'prompt hello' doesn't work, whereas select are OK.

Code:

```
$stmt = oci_parse($conn, "prompt hello");
if (!oci_execute($stmt)){
    var_dump(oci_error($stmt));
    ....
```

This returns me the error 'ORA 00900 Invalid sql statement'. Indeed I tested it on the same server / user / SID from sql-developer and the prompt has no error itself...

Any idea why?